# Use Algolia Search with Firebase Database in Xcode iOS Swift

Tags: ios, firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database, algolia

I'm trying to connect my Firebase Database with Algolia Search.
I follow this following link from Algolia.
https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/indexing/3rd-party-service/firebase-algolia/

It says I got to create a Node.js application, so I did it.
Then to create a file called .env and Generate New Private Key from Firebase (what I did).

But the next step is a little bit strange because it asks me to create a JavaScript file called index.js in the "Create" section of the link I provide you.
From the "Create" section I'm very confused, and I don't know if this link is a right way to connect my Firebase Database and Algolia for Search.

If someone now how to do that, he will help me a lot.
Thanks in advance for your advice or tutorials if you have.

First I got to create an .env file (this is the name of the file not an extension)
[image: The .env file]

Here's the "Create" section what I'm talking about
[image: The "Create" section]

Third steps is for connect the Firebase database (I try to connect mine)
[image: load contacts]

Then I got to run node index.js in the Terminal. But the Terminal said FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Can't determine Firebase Database URL. Be sure to include database URL option when calling firebase.initializeApp().

Here's my index.js file :

```
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
var firebaseAdmin = require("firebase-admin");
var algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');

// load values from the .env file in this directory into process.env
dotenv.load();

// configure firebase
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");
firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
  credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL // Here the error
});
var database = firebaseAdmin.database();

var algolia = algoliasearch(process.env.ALGOLIA_APP_ID, process.env.ALGOLIA_API_KEY); 

// Index for Algolia with my database
var index = algolia.initIndex('users');

// Begin import
var contactsRef = database.ref("/users"); // My table calls users in firebase
contactsRef.once('value', initialImport);
function initialImport(dataSnapshot) {
  // Array of data to index
  var objectsToIndex = [];
  // Get all objects
  var values = dataSnapshot.val();
  // Process each child Firebase object
  dataSnapshot.forEach((function(childSnapshot) {
    // get the key and data from the snapshot
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    // Specify Algolia's objectID using the Firebase object key
    childData.objectID = childKey;
    // Add object for indexing
    objectsToIndex.push(childData);
  }))
  // Add or update new objects
  index.saveObjects(objectsToIndex, function(err, content) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log('Firebase -> Algolia import done');
    process.exit(0);
  });
}
// End Algolia import
```

Now my .env file I created but it seems doesn't work :

```
ALGOLIA_APP_ID=TFISJH1AP3 // The name app in Algolia
ALGOLIA_API_KEY=83bd61cd47159f... // Secret Key
FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL=https://live-event-3989e.firebaseio.com // Maybe here it's not like that I got to write my firebase URL ?
```

Comment: [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fulltext-search) is a sample

Comment: Did you tried yourself ? Because I already saw this page today and didn't help me

Comment: Hi, "From the "Create" section I'm very confused" Can you explain which part is confusing to you? Thanks.

Comment: Ok I will edit my question with the scrrenshot of the section I have troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Set manuell

```
firebase.initializeApp({
    databaseURL: "https://<yourURL>.firebaseio.com",
});
```

and

```
const ALGOLIA_APP_ID = '<your id>';
const ALGOLIA_API_KEY = '<your key>';


// configure algolia
const algolia = algoliasearch(
  ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
  ALGOLIA_API_KEY
);
```